# Should taxonomy terms such as Crustacea be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

Should taxonomy terms such as Crustacea be capitalized?  I think yes, but am unsure.

Comment: The word *Crustacea* is a proper noun in English, yes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends on which level of taxonomy that term is. For genus and higher, names are capitalized. Species and terms more specific than species (like variety and subspecies) are not capitalized.

Thus, for your example, Crustacea should be capitalized because it is a subphylum.

More details can be found [here](http://communications.med.nyu.edu/advertising-branding/editorial-style-guide/nomenclature-and-taxonomy).

Comment: "I don't eat mammals, but poultry." Does "mammals" need to be capitalized?

Comment: @Blessed Geek The taxonomic name of the group of mammals is Mammalia. The former is not capitalized, the latter is.

Comment: Moreover, genus and species (and subspecies, if any) are to be set in italic, but higher taxa should be set in roman.

Comment: Upvote for proper plural of *taxon* by @tchrist.

Comment: The link in the answer now redirects to a login screen.